# How do I copy one vector to another vector in Java without updating the original vector?

Tags: java, vector, copy

I am copying a vector to another vector of same type.And modifying the copy vector but the original vector is also getting update I don't understand why?

```
Vector<allocated>finished_copy=new Vector<allocated>();
finished_copy=finished;
```

I am printing the value of original vector after and before modification

```
for(int k=0;k<finished.size();k++) {
        System.out.print(finished.elementAt(k).output);
        System.out.print(finished.elementAt(k).step);
        System.out.println();
}//some modification on finished_copy
```

And printing the original but both are different

Please help me in this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not doing any copy. All you're doing is assigning the same Vector to another variable:

Before:

```
finished ------> [a, b, c, d]
```

After:

```
finished ------> [a, b, c, d]
                 ^
                 |
finished_copy ---/
```

Here's how you would copy all the elements of a Vector into another one:

```
Vector<Allocated> finishedCopy = new Vector<>(finished);
```

or

```
Vector<Allocated> finishedCopy = new Vector<>();
finishedCopy.addAll(finished);
```

This, however, will create two different vectors containing references to the same Allocated instances. If what you want is a copy of those objects, then you need to create explicit copies. Without doing a copy, changing the state of an object in the first list will also change its state in the second one, since both lists contain references to the same ojects.

Note that:

- classes should start with an uppercase letter
- variables should not contain underscares, but be camelCased
- Vector should not be used anymore. ArrayList should be, since Java 2. We're at Java 8.

Comment: Thanks Nizet for your feedback.I think I need explicit copies of objects.Should I iterate over content of original one and copy one by one or Is there any predefined method?

Comment: You should create a copy constructor, i.e a constructor in Allocated that takes another instance of Allocated as argument, and copies the state.

Answer (score 1):

When you assign the reference to your `finished_copy` you make the `new Vector()` unreachable. This,

```
Vector<allocated>finished_copy=new Vector<allocated>();
finished_copy=finished;
```

should be something like (using [this `Vector` constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html#Vector%28java.util.Collection%29))

```
Vector<allocated>finished_copy=new Vector<>(finished);
```

Note, this is still a shallow copy of the contents of `finished`.